# How to make OR condition in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, sql

What parameters should be passed to WP_Query to get such sql code?

`where post_type = "post" or post_author = 123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WP_Query` does not handle this sort of query: use two instances of `WP_Query`, and then combine the results.

Untested code:

```php
$posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
) );

$post_ids = array_column( $posts->posts, 'ID' );

$author = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'    => 'any',
    'author'       => 123,
    'post__not_in' => $post_ids, // prevent duplicates
) );

$combined = array_merge( $posts->posts, $author->posts );
```

There are filters inside of `WP_Query` that you can use to modify the SQL statement (ex: [`posts_where`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/)), but need to be careful as it can impact other queries.